# Вставка youtube как iframe

Tags: html, youtube, iframe, youtube-api

Мне надо вставить страницу конкретного юзера в Youtube через `iframe`. Получился вот такой код:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/user/danpetruk/videos?flow=grid&view=0"></iframe>
```

Однако `iframe` не отобразился, а консоль хрома выдала ошибку:

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

Насколько я понимаю, это означает то, что Youtube запрещает использовать себя как `iframe`. Как обойти данное ограничение?

Comment: Кнопка "Поделиться"...

Comment: @isterm кнопка Поделиться работает только для видеороликов, но не как не для страницы пользователя

Comment: "Веб-сайт не позволяет отображать своё содержимое во фрейме. Оно должно отображаться в отдельном окне." 

Как обойти? Загрузите и обработайте страницу у себя на сервере, уберите лишние заголовки и скрипты.

Comment: @isterm а как-нибудь без серверной части обойтись можно?

Comment: Можно получить данные через API и отрендерить на клиенте.

Answer (score -1):

Смотря для чего вам нужно отображать информацию о пользователе и какую. Может стоит использовать API ютуба?
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.